# How can I distinguish the different Textarea fields in apex?

Tags: apex, fields, describefieldresult

In Salesforce there are 3 different Text Area fields:

`Text Area`, `Text Area (Long)`, and `Text Area (Rich)`.

I'm doing some processing in a custom class and I need to distinguish between the 3 different kinds.  My first thought was using Describe but the `Schema.DisplayType` enum value for all three is simply `TextArea`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for short vs long:
http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/03/find-length-of-salesforce-field-in-apex.html

When I test the following in my org:

```
System.debug(
    Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.Description.getLength()
);
```

I get 32000 back. When I try custom text areas, rich or not, I get the appropriate values back too. Doesn't indicate richness though. For that you can use `.Description.isHtmlFormatted()` which seems to return TRUE for rich and FALSE for plaintext.